# Conceptional approach sharing code between AndoidStudio Project and IntelliJ Project

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, shared-libraries, shared

I need consulting on setting up a project correctly. Maybe someone has a good approach for my problem ?

I have some Classes in a Package, which I would like to share between an Android Application (Android Studio) and a Maintainance Application (IntelliJ IDE).

I know that in the end it will be a .jar that both IDE's should import.

But I am unsure how to setup this correctly. Should I create a seperate module in IntelliJ for the shared part and then howto reference this in Android Studio ?

Do I need to use a local maven repo for this ?

What is a good approach for this ?

Comment: Android Studio and IntelliJ are based on the same source. You can easily open an IntelliJ project in Android Studio and vice versa without problems

Comment: But my projects are different regarding SDK. Android-APP uses Android-SDK. My Maintainance App uses simply Java 8. Now I would like to share code between 2 seperate Projects, preferrable running in 2 different IDE's.

Comment: So? There's still no problem. You can configure different languages and/or SDKs for modules in the same project, but you'll need actual modules for that. I personally had a project with a Java and a Python module in it, both of which worked without problems. Syntax highlighting and actual development is a separate issue, but there's nothing preventing you from using two IDE's on a two-platform project. See also LibGDX: cross-platform Java game library, usually developed in Android Studio *even with a standard Java module*, but there's nothing preventing you from using Android Studio.

Comment: The point being, whether you use one, two, three, or more SDK's in different modules doesn't matter, as long as the IDE is able to recognize them

Comment: Ok. Thanks I will try. But when having 2 modules in the same IDE, how can I share the code ? I mean one module should be the master for the shared code. Or is it a 3rd Module for the shared code ?

Comment: If you have code shared by two modules, create a third module. If one module uses everything in the other, you import the second one.

Comment: Perfect thank you and have a good day.